# error TS2339: Property 'clipboard' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I get this error in my project, that I am updating - they want to copy data to the clipboard. Custom data, that I can easily put together

error TS2339: Property 'clipboard' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Loading from './Loading';
import axios from 'axios';
import { AppConfig } from '../../Config';
import 'jquery-ui-bundle';
// import 'jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.css';
import '../helpers/datepicker-skins/jquery-ui-1.10.1.css';
import '../helpers/datepicker-skins/cangas.datepicker.css';

class Log extends React.Component<any, any> {
    validationCheck(): any {}

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { FaultyUnits: [], FaultyUnitsPackages: [] };
    }
...
    public CopyEmailAddresses(event: any): void {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText("this.state.textToCopy");  <---- error on this line
    }
```

When typing, the suggestions shows the clipboard and writetext, but when saving/compiling it does not accept it.

When clicking F12 (go to Defenition) on the clipboard I get lib.dom.d.ts:

```
....
/** The state and the identity of the user agent. It allows scripts to query it and to register themselves to carry on some activities. */
interface Navigator extends NavigatorAutomationInformation, NavigatorConcurrentHardware, NavigatorContentUtils, NavigatorCookies, NavigatorID, NavigatorLanguage, NavigatorNetworkInformation, NavigatorOnLine, NavigatorPlugins, NavigatorStorage {
    /** Available only in secure contexts. */
    readonly clipboard: Clipboard;
    /** Available only in secure contexts. */
    readonly credentials: CredentialsContainer;
    readonly doNotTrack: string | null;
....
```

And when I navigate into the Clipboard class I see what I expect - read and write functions.

I have been reading about this issue half of the day, I am out of ideas.

Any ideas from you guys?

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/*.ts",
    "config"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have a secure context?

Comment: @DanielW. `TS2239` is a `tsc` compile-time error, not a runtime browser JavaScript error. The OP should read this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26728

Comment: @Dai I have been there, and I can repeat the question there "where do I put that?". Ok, I can put in the top of the file. Then I use this code  
 (navigator as NavigatorExtended).clipboard
      .writeText("event.target.innerText")
      .then(() => {
        alert("Copied!");
      }); 
and get this error "Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)" on (navigator as NavigatorExtended)
Oh they joy of old projects...

Comment: @sonnich Show us your `tsconfig.json` file. Also, verify that _that_ specific `tsconfig.json` file is being used when you build your project (as it's very easy for VS, `tsc`, `npm` and other JS tooling to end-up using their own distinct, and often subtly different `tsconfig.json` files). I suspect you're seeing one particular build work (or F12 working in VS) because it assumes it can use the latest `lib.dom.d.ts` with `Navigator.clipboard` but another build fails because it uses a different `lib.dom.d.ts` _without_ `Navigator.clipboard`.

Comment: @Dai I added the tsconfig.json to the question. How do I check which file is used for compiling?

Comment: I tried it all over, and not I get this error: "Interface 'NavigatorClipboard' incorrectly extends interface 'Navigator'.
  Types of property 'clipboard' are incompatible.
    Type 'Clipboard' is missing the following properties from type 'Clipboard': read, readText, write, addEventListener, and 2 more.ts(2430)" on this line: "  interface NavigatorClipboard extends Navigator" - what is this?

Comment: ok, it works now. Adding "skipLibCheck": true to the config, then it accepts it. Behaiviour is interesting, in chrome it did not work, but it worked in firefox. And now it works in Chrome as well.

Comment: "skipLibCheck": true didn't work for me

Answer (score 12):

You should try:

```
window.navigator['clipboard'].writeText("this.state.textToCopy");
```

Instead of:

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText("this.state.textToCopy");
```

Comment: Thanks. This is closed, but for the fun of it I might try this next week

Comment: window.navigator['clipboard'] worked, thanks